# How to append each item in the list using loop?

Tags: bash, shell-script, locale

I am trying to create a locale script in bash to automatically set the `lc_ctype` to the array and then local-gen. The issue I am facing is appending each array item to the desired locale.

```
declare -a arr=(
    "NUMERIC",
    "TIME",
    "MONETARY",
    "PAPER",
    "MEASUREMENT")

lc_ctype="en_US.UTF-8"

for i in ${arr[@]};
  do
     lc="LC_${i}=$lc_ctype"
     echo $lc
  done
```

The output:

```
LC_NUMERIC,=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME,=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY,=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER,=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
```

How can I get the output as below without the comma?

```
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Remove the commas from the contents of the array when you create it. They are not needed. Also, setting `LC_ALL` sets all `LC_` variables.

Comment: You don't need an array and a for loop for this... `printf '%s\n' LC_{NUMERIC,TIME,MONETARY,PAPER,MEASUREMENT}="${lc_ctype}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove commas:

```
declare -a arr=(
    "NUMERIC"
    "TIME"
    "MONETARY"
    "PAPER"
    "MEASUREMENT")
```

Answer (score 2):

The unexpected output is due to the commas in the assignment of the array elements. These may be removed as they are not part of the syntax and therefore not needed (unless you want commas there, that is).

A less complicated loop for you:

```
printf "LC_%s=$lc_ctype\n" "${arr[@]}"
```

or, without the array:

```
printf "LC_%s=$lc_ctype\n" NUMERIC TIME MONETARY PAPER MEASUREMENT
```

Depending on the purpose of this exercise, it may be worth noting that setting the value of `LC_ALL` will have the same effect as setting the values of all `LC_` variables individually to the same value.

Answer (score 1):

The commas are from your array, try it like this:

```
declare -a arr=(
    "NUMERIC"
    "TIME"
    "MONETARY"
    "PAPER"
    "MEASUREMENT")
```